# Roslyn CTP - How to Write Changes To File System

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, roslyn

I created an empty Visual Studio Solution called Solution.sln which I load into the workspace int the first line.  Then I add a project to the solution, and update the workspace to the latest solution which should now contain a project.  How do I write out the files for the new stuff I added to the empty solution?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;
using Roslyn.Services;

namespace RoslynMainApp 
{
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            IWorkspace workspace = Workspace.LoadSolution(@"C:\RoslynSolutions\Solution.sln");
            ProjectId projectId;

            ISolution solution = Solution.Create(SolutionId.CreateNewId("Solution"));
            solution.AddCSharpProject("Project1.dll", "Project1", out projectId);
            var success = workspace.ApplyChanges(workspace.CurrentSolution, solution); 
            if(success)
            {
                //How do I write out all the stuff I just added to Solution.sln to the directory RoslynSolutions?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Bob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The act of calling `ApplyChanges` should write the changes to disk.  However, note that in CTP1, only a small set of the changes you can apply to solutions are actually implemented.

Comment: All I added was a single project to a solution which should be implemented.  Feel free to copy and paste my example into a console window and let me know if it works on your machine.

Comment: In CTP1, the only things that were supported was adding, updating, and removing documents. Adding or removing projects was not supported.

Comment: Looks like they just released a new CTP today.  I'll try it out and inform everyone if this limitation has been removed in CTP2 or not.

Comment: I'll save you the trouble and tell you that CTP2 does not support AddProject either through workspaces loaded via Workspace.LoadSolution. There's now an API `IsSupported` on IWorkspace which documents which modification actions are actually supported.